# undefined method `edit_user_password_url'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, clearance

I am trying to do forgot password using clearance but getting this error ???

```
undefined method `edit_user_password_url' for #<#<Class:0x00000003898f98>:0x00000003757d50>
```

At this line

```
<%= link_to t(".link_text", default: "Change my password"),
    edit_user_password_url(@user, token: @user.confirmation_token.html_safe) %>
</p>

<p><%= raw t(".closing") %></p>
```

```
<p><%= raw t(".closing") %></p>
```

Here is my password controller code

```
class PasswordsController < ApplicationController

    layout 'login'
    skip_before_filter :require_login, only: [:create, :edit, :new, :update], raise: false
    skip_before_filter :authorize, only: [:create, :edit, :new, :update], raise: false
    before_filter :ensure_existing_user, only: [:edit, :update]

    skip_before_action :authenticate_user, :except => [:destroy]


    def new
    end

    def create
        if user = find_user_for_create
            user.forgot_password!
            deliver_email(user)
            flash[:notice] = t('password.send_email')
            redirect_to  sign_in_path
        else
            flash[:notice] = t('password.invalid_email')
            render 'new'
        end

    end

    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    end

    def update
        @user = find_user_for_update
        if @user.update_password password_reset_params
            #Activity.add_activity(@user,'forgot_password','')
            sign_in @user
            redirect_to sign_in_path
        else

        end
    end

  private
    def deliver_email(user)
        mail = ::ClearanceMailer.change_password(user)
        if Gem::Version.new(Rails::VERSION::STRING) >= Gem::Version.new("4.2.0")
            mail.deliver_later
        else
            mail.deliver
        end
    end

    def password_reset_params
        if params.has_key? :user
            ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn %{Since locales functionality was added, accessing params[:user] is no longer supported.}
            params[:user][:password]
        else
            params[:password_reset][:password]
        end
    end

    def find_user_by_id_and_confirmation_token
        user_param = Clearance.configuration.user_id_parameter
        Clearance.configuration.user_model.
        find_by_id_and_confirmation_token params[user_param], params[:token].to_s
    end

    def find_user_for_create
        Clearance.configuration.user_model.
        find_by_normalized_email params[:password][:email]
    end


    def find_user_for_update
        find_user_by_id_and_confirmation_token
    end

    def ensure_existing_user
        unless find_user_by_id_and_confirmation_token
            flash_failure_when_forbidden
            render template: "passwords/new"
        end
    end

    def flash_failure_when_forbidden
        flash.now[:notice] = translate(:forbidden,
        scope: [:clearance, :controllers, :passwords],
        default: t('flashes.failure_when_forbidden'))
    end

    def flash_failure_after_update
        flash.now[:notice] = translate(:blank_password,
        scope: [:clearance, :controllers, :passwords],
        default: t('flashes.failure_after_update'))
    end


end
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your controller. The **route** is not defined, we need to see your `routes.rb`.

Comment: Type `rake routes` and find valid URL helper name in list.

Comment: okay let me try and show you my result

Comment: there is no routes defined for edit_user_password

Comment: Usually you get this message when the route helper doesn't find the path to which you are referring.  If you add the route to your routes.rb file you should be on your way.  Just to be sure, what is the output of rake routes?

Comment: Please show use your `config/routes.rb`.